# Could not look up Document ID due to an error encountered in Microsoft Search Server

Tags: search, document-id

Today I'm facing a problem with Document ID look-up, after went through all the steps:

- Activate Document ID and Document Set feature
- Run Document ID job assignment and Document enable timer job

My Document ID column was finally created successfully, however when I browse the link `_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=MYID-5-2` this error shows up:

> Could not look up Document ID "MYID-5-2" due to an error encountered in Microsoft Search Server. Error in the application.

I've googled for so long but could not find a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue with SharePoint app pool 80.

You can not use network services account. Instead choose a "domain administrator" account.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/b87c5fc6-c330-4e10-ac71-be52b8a9673f/